# How to get the latest value of a duplicate key in a Map in java?

Tags: java, collections

Following is my requirement: I have to count the occurrence of a particular item in a List and then print the item along with its occurrence count. For this I have the following code:

```
public void countOccurrences(Collection<String> list){
      Map<String, Integer> occurrenceMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

      for(String obj: list){
           Integer numOccurrence = occurrenceMap.get(obj);
           if(numOccurrence == null){
                //first count
                occurrenceMap.put(obj, 1);
           } else{
                occurrenceMap.put(obj, numOccurrence++);

           }
      }
      for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : occurrenceMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" : "+entry.getValue());
    }
  }
```

Now say for example items added to my list are as follows:

```
list.add("apple");
list.add("apple");
list.add("apple");
list.add("banana");
list.add("banana");
list.add("mango");
```

The output that I'm expecting is

```
apple:3
banana:2
mango:1
```

However, the output that is coming is

```
apple:1
banana:1
mango:1
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: try ++numOccurence instead

Comment: `x++` increments `x` *after* it is assigned, not before.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the logic in your else part

```
 occurrenceMap.put(obj, ++numOccurrence);
```

Because the post increment

```
numOccurrence ++
```

Returns the value of `numOccurrence`  and then increments `numOccurrence`'s value by 1. Hence you are not putting the latest one in the map.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change

`occurrenceMap.put(obj, numOccurrence++);`

to

`occurrenceMap.put(obj, numOccurrence + 1);` or `occurrenceMap.put(obj, ++numOccurrence);`

`numOccurrence++` will increment `numOccurrence` after the statement. And it will never be used as `numOccurrence` is reasigned next time the loop goes around.

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this way :

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("apple");
list.add("apple");
list.add("apple");
list.add("banana");
list.add("banana");
list.add("mango");

Set<String> unique = new HashSet<String>(list);
for (String key : unique) {
 System.out.println(key + ": " + Collections.frequency(list, key));
}
```

Output:

```
banana: 2
apple: 3
mango: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use following piece of code to achieve your objective.

```
public static void countOccurrences(Collection<String> list){
  Map<String, Integer> occurrenceMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
  Integer temp;
  for(String obj: list){
       if((temp = occurrenceMap.put(obj, 1))!= null){
            occurrenceMap.put(obj, ++temp);
       }
  }
  for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : occurrenceMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" : "+entry.getValue());
    }
}
```